# Django Admin List Filter Remove All Option

Tags: python, django, filter, django-admin, django-filter

As you can see from the screenshot bellow, When using and customizing django admin filters like so:

```
class DealExpiredListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'expired'

    parameter_name = 'expired'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('yes', 'yes'),
            ('no', 'no'),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == "yes":
            return queryset.filter(end_date__lt=timezone.now())
        elif self.value() == "no":
            return queryset.exclude(end_date__lt=timezone.now())
```

Django will insert an "All" option at any case (which is great for %99 of the times).
I want to rename or remove that "All" option as can bee seen in the screenshot

[image: scrrenshot]

Answer (score 15):

I eventually solved it by browsing the source code which can be found [here in this link][1] and overriding the `choices` function. I only changed the "All" selection to show "Yes" in this code that was added to my filter class :

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

def choices(self, changelist):
    """Copied from source code to remove the "All" Option"""
    yield {
        'selected': self.value() is None,
        'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({}, [self.parameter_name]),
        'display': 'Yes',
    }
    for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
        yield {
            'selected': self.value() == force_text(lookup),
            'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.parameter_name: lookup}, []),
            'display': title,
        }
```

As Linh mentioned: For anyone only want to remove the all option just delete `'display': 'Yes'`, from the first yield{} in choices function
[1]: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/filters.py#L44

Comment: If you have languages in your project make sure to use django translations:
`from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`
`_('Yes')`

Comment: For anyone only want to remove the all option just delete `'display': 'Yes',` from the first yield{} in choices function

Comment: If I could upvote this 7x I would.  Thanks a million.  And for those who don't want to see the All option at all, just comment out the first yield block.  Beautiful!

Comment: I might be wrong but force_text might have been deprecated starting Django 4.0 so you'll have to look at the latest source code if that's indeed the case

Comment: Here's a link that won't change as `main` changes. I'm pretty sure what was meant in the original answer: https://github.com/django/django/blob/0f3b1a783dfa36cb23aae0bb954756d0edcd9fc1/django/contrib/admin/filters.py#L150-L154

Answer (score 1):

You can copy, paste and override [choices()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4593bc5da115f2e808a803a4ec24104b6c7a6152/django/contrib/admin/filters.py#L114) then uncomment `"display": _("All"),` as shown below to remove **`All` option** from Django Admin filter:

```py
class DealExpiredListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    def choices(self, changelist): # Here
        yield {
            "selected": self.value() is None,
            "query_string": changelist.get_query_string(remove=[self.parameter_name]),
            # "display": _("All"), # Here
        }
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {
                "selected": self.value() == str(lookup),
                "query_string": changelist.get_query_string(
                    {self.parameter_name: lookup}
                ),
                "display": title,
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps even cleaner, if you're looking to remove the All option entirely, is simply to pop off (consume) the first item from the generator. The `yield` in the source code you found in the Django source is a python keyword that means 'each time you ask for a new value, return the next one, until we run out'

It makes it possible to have a big list of things but only load one into memory at a time and some other neat side benefits. You trigger the consume behavior when you add the generator into a loop, but you can do it one at a time with the `next` function.

So this would be a really nice way to pop off the 'All' while still working with any changes Django makes in the future:

```py
class DealExpiredListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    def choices(self, changelist):
        choices = super().choices(changelist)
        next(choices)
        return choices
```

Comment: This solution is more elegant and way more stable against changes of the underlying code base. Best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

### All or Nothing?

This is a solution based on the above answers, but using Django 4.1. Django 4.1 implements a `Clear all filters` button *(#27888 closed Cleanup/optimization (fixed) Add a button to clear all admin filters)* which appears after the admin user has made a filter selection, and when pressed essentially provides the `All` option by the back door as it were. In addition there is the question of what the page should display before the admin user has made a filter selection at all - again this is the same as the `All` option. In my implementation it makes no sense to be able to  view all the records (races) for all events (the fk filter) together in a huge list, I only want to be able to view all the races for a single event at a time. When you provide a custom list filter class you are required to implement `lookups` and `queryset` functions as described by the op. Here are mine:

```
class NoAllListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'event'
    parameter_name = 'event__name'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            tuple((event.name, event.name) for event in Event.objects.all())
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(event__name = self.value())
```

My `queryset` function is different to the documented example in `ModelAdmin List Filters` in that it does not check `self.value()` first, so when no event selection has been made, or `Clear all filters` is pressed, it provides a queryset which doesn't match any records at all, which is actually what I want.

By contrast, this modified `queryset` function, which is more like the documented example, but which does not suit my purpose, produces a queryset which displays all records (all races in all events) when no event selection has been made, or when `Clear all filters` is pressed ***(counter-example only - not used)***:

```
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(event__name = self.value())
```

Returning to my first, implemented, `queryset` function (not the counter example), to align with the `0 races` displayed when no event selection has been made, or when `Clear all filters` is pressed, instead of commenting out the initially generated `choices` yield, I changed the display from `All` to `None`. Logically `Clear all filters` really, and in most cases, means don't filter anything and display all records, but in this instance I think the `None` option replacing the `All` makes it clear that no records are expected to be displayed. Here is my modified Django 4.1 `choices` function in the `NoAllListFilter` class:

```
    def choices(self, changelist):
        # Modified from Django 4.1 source
        yield {
            "selected": self.value() is None,
            "query_string": changelist.get_query_string(remove=[self.parameter_name]),
            # "display": _("All"),
            "display": _("None"),
        }
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {
                "selected": self.value() == str(lookup),
                "query_string": changelist.get_query_string(
                    {self.parameter_name: lookup}
                ),
                "display": title,
            }
```

Note that the comment that the method `force_text` has been deprecated from Django 4.0 onwards is doubtless correct but no longer applicable because the Django 4.1 `choices` function just uses `str(lookup)` rather than `force_text(lookup)`